# Rule to redirect file based on timestamp?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I need to filter JSON files based on date and time that is present on it's name.

If file name `datetime.json` is bigger than current time I want to redirect to `future.json`.

If file name is less than current time, then don't redirect.

#### For example:

Current date and time is `1377512625`. File Name is `1345732202`. Current date and time is greater than File Name, then serve `1345732202.json`:

```
http://myserver.com/1345732202.json
```

Current date and time is `1377512625`. File Name is `1408804202`. Current date and time is less than File Name, then serve `future.json`:

```
http://myserver.com/1408804202.json
```

#### Here is my `.htaccess` which does not work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{TIME} <%{REQUEST_FILENAME} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.json$ /future.json [R=307,L]
```

Comment: I can't test it here, but the documentation says that `<` compares two strings. You probably want to test two integers, which can be done with `-lt`. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: Numerical operators are only available in Apache 2.4. Which version of Apache do you have?

Comment: @anubhava, Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)

Comment: In that case you cannot do numerical comparison using mod_rewrite :(

Comment: Why don't you internally redirect to a PHP code that will check the timestamp and redirect to the proper JSON instead? `RewriteRule ^(\d+)\.json$ /check_json.php?timestamp=$1 [L]`. From the `check_json.php` you can redirect it again to the proper file you wish to serve or give the content you wish for that timestamp.

Comment: So you have what? a cached file for every microsecond? Something doesn't look good.

Comment: This is good solution, @Prix, if there isn't a way without PHP.

Comment: @akostadinov, I'll not have file for every microsecond. Maybe I'll have 100-200 files, but some of them in "future".

Comment: @dibo, that would make what you want pretty useless. Because you want to take current milliseconds and open that file if it exists. It seems like you just want to cache a php request for up to 100-200 milliseconds and I don't think this is the way to do it. Perhaps edit your question to say what exactly are you trying to achieve and why.

Comment: @akostadinov, no. I want to compare current milliseconds with the "milliseconds name" of the file. "Greater than" (>) and "less than" (<), not "equal" (=).

Comment: @dibo, what you want seems impossible. There is also an ext httpd filter you may use but what you want is slow IMO. You'd better modify the application to request the necessary file, much easier. If you are really using this for caching you also avoid problems with client machine clock skew which are very common. This is the filter just in case - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ext_filter.html